# Stephen Wolfram’s new class of models

Tags: foundations

Does the physics community have a consensus view on Stephen Wolfram’s “A Class of Models with the Potential to Represent Fundamental Physics”?

Comment: The overwhelming consensus is that there’s nothing of substance there, but a lot of big claims and flashy press. In other words, precisely nothing has changed since Wolfram began making grand claims 20 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  But (question for the moderator) I don’t understand why the question was closed down as “opinion-based”. What opinion do you see in my question?